# RDD get datatype for each elements - pyspark

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I am trying to write a customized inferschema codes for RDD. I want to get a list of datatypes for each elements in row of RDD. But when I try mapper to do that, it seems like type(x) for each elements causes error because referring RDD from an action or transformation. Is there any work around to do this?

Attempt#1

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])
def type(partition):
    for row in partition:
        for val in row:
            yield {'a':type(val)}

dttype = sample.mapPartitions(type)
dttype.collect()
```

if I do collect, this is what i get

> Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or
>   reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations
>   and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other
>   transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() *
>   x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action
>   cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more
>   information, see SPARK-5063.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far and the errors produced

Comment: @desertnaut Just added!

Comment: @desertnaut nvm this worked lol i made another mistake named type :(

Comment: you can make DataFrom from your RDD and it can infer schema from your set automatically. They you can get types for each column in `df.fields`

Comment: @IuriiNedostup Thanks, but I want to make one with different conditions on determining types